# Dealing with "Request for Work" type questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

First off, this is what our main closure and off topic dialogs look like at present:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

---

SO seems to be tackling "Request for Work" type questions head on as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185142/what-should-the-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be-for-stack-overflow

> Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

We see such questions fairly often too, with a long list of requirements that essentially boils down to: ***Write a complete script/macro/program for me that does X, Y and Z***. No code included or anything to indicate what has been tried yet. Shouldn't we take similar steps like SO has (or plans to) and add a closure reason for such questions? What do you all think?

Comment: doesn't too broad or unclear handle this? [so] has that reason because the volume of plz-send-me-teh-codez is pretty huge - I don't recall seeing _too_ many of those

Comment: Do you happen to have some examples of what you find a good example of this?

Comment: @IvoFlipse For example: http://superuser.com/questions/592942/how-to-code-this-macro, http://superuser.com/questions/586940/how-to-merge-with-macro, etc

Comment: And two more (from my answer on *What should be featured in our list of off-topic close reasons?*): [AHK script to toggle hidden folders in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/609347/ahk-script-to-toggle-hidden-folders-in-windows-8) and [script to scroll page by cursor movement - add the option to pause and change speed with keystrokes](http://superuser.com/questions/608281/script-to-scroll-page-by-cursor-movement-add-the-option-to-pause-and-change-sp)

Comment: @IvoFlipse: As has been pointed out, these sorts of questions are by no means a rarity here on SU either.

Comment: @Sathya: See the examples above and there are many more in the same vein. Yes, some of them might be classified as being unclear, but what of those that are clear and yet expect a complete spoon-feeding type solution with no effort having been put in? (BTW, just saying "I tried and failed" or "I know nothing about this" doesn't qualify as evidence of adequate effort IMO.)